# Проблема в архитектуре приложения: итерации и циклы

Tags: c++, windows, архитектура, итераторы

Постараюсь описать всё как можно покороче.
Вот цикл программы, в котором выполняется обновление сообщений от Windows окна:

```
while( msg.message != WM_QUIT )
{
    if( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE ) )
        {
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }
}
```

Кто работал с Виндой – знает. И, собственно, выполнение самой программы. Например, мне необходимо проиграть аудио файл в ф-ции подобной этой:

```
playSound( const string& file_name )
{
    while( !engOfFile() )
    {
        // There is sound are playing...
    }
}
```

Однако нам мешает следующее: в playSound(...) есть цикл который повторяет итерации на протяжении воспроизведения песни. Получается, что пока итерирует цикл принятия смс-оk от окна, sound are not playing. Так же само и наоборот: пока sound are playing, программу сложно закрыть, кроме как через диспетчер задач (и виден круглый курсор). В итоге: *оба цикла мешают друг другу*.

```
playSound( "music.ogg" );
Window->update( );

// Anyway, we've got an issue.

Window->update( );
playSound( "music.ogg" );
```

Что посоветуете? Уже думал над отдельным потоком, но реализовать не вышло. Есть какие-то идеи, кто писал код под Windows?

Comment: Вы уже знаете о [потоках](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)?

Comment: кроме того, waveform audio позволяет проигрывать звуковые файлы асинхронно (смотрите API с префиксом `waveOut`)

Comment: @mega, т.е. можно реализовать обновления с помощью потоков? Можно легкий пример? Так проще будет.

Comment: По правде говоря, пока мне нужен только *.ogg.

Comment: В принципе, в сети много примеров, вот первый же нагугленный: 
 [Playing and Recording Sound via the Wave API](http://bcbcaq.freeservers.com/project_WaveRecord.html). Смотрите сразу _playback wrapper functions_. Суть тут для ридера и врайтера примерно одинаковая: готовим буферы, в которые последовательно загружаем звуковые данные и передаем эти буферы в систему, а она уже Вас уведомляет о их завершении или ошибках через колбеки или через оконные уведомления.

Comment: ogg, насколько я знаю, напрямую не поддерживается Windows. [PlaySound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx), например конвертировать ogg точно не будет. Вам придется конвертировать его перед воспроизведением, в WAV, например. Для этого тоже есть свой API (смотрите функции с префиком `acm`). Подобрать кодек можно с помощью вызова [acmFormatSuggest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742916(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите пример [Playing and Recording Sound via the Wave API](http://bcbcaq.freeservers.com/project_WaveRecord.html).

Смотрите сразу *playback wrapper functions*.

Суть тут для воспроизведения и записи звука примерно одинаковая: готовим буферы, в которые последовательно загружаем звуковые данные и передаем эти буферы в систему, а она уже Вас уведомляет о их завершении или ошибках через колбеки или через оконные уведомления.

---

Формат `ogg`, насколько я знаю, напрямую не поддерживается Windows. [PlaySound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx), например конвертировать `ogg` точно не будет. Вам придется конвертировать его перед воспроизведением, в `WAV`, например. Для этого тоже есть свой API (смотрите функции с префиком `acm`). Подобрать кодек можно с помощью вызова [acmFormatSuggest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742916(v=vs.85).aspx).

Подробности - в MSDN: [Converting Data from One Format to Another](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797805(v=vs.85).aspx)

---

Самый простой способ асинхронно проиграть файл, на мой взгляд - [PlaySound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
PlaySound(TEXT("recycle.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
```

но учитывайте предыдущее замечание относительно этой функции касательно `ogg`.