# Бесконечный цикл перед PeekMessage

Tags: c++, winapi, циклы

Всем доброй ночи. Все-таки не успокоюсь, пока не решу окончательно одну проблему. В этот раз постараюсь получше изъяснится, т.к. в прошлый никто не помог, да и в общем, проблему не так поняли. Вот вам тело одной ф-ции:

```
auto sound = audio_system->LoadSound("gong.ogg");

        sound->SetVolume(0.05f);
        sound->Play();


MSG msg = {0};

        while(sound->IsPlaying() == true)
        {
            while(msg.message != WM_QUIT)
            {
                audio_system->Streaming(*sound);

                if(PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE))
                {
                    TranslateMessage(&msg);
                    DispatchMessage(&msg);
                }
                else
                    break;

                if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                    return;
            }
        }
```

Знаю, это ни словами, ни матом не описать, но только вот это все решает мою an issue. В консольных apps все ok, да вот с Win32, что-то не так. Это AcousticsLib, если кому-то полезней знать, чтобы решить задачу. Только перед стриимингом можно изменить громкось, источника, вот поэтому я с этим хочу попарится. В общем-то, `audio_system->Streaming(*sound);` должен быть в true-цикле, пока играет один sound. Иначе, он попросту не будет играть. Streaming не дает обновляться окну, пока он не завепшит playSound. Это единственный код, что у меня работает. Потоки либо не давали никакого эффекта, либо программа крэшилась. Причем это один sound, а что если я два и более захочу? Хотелось бы:

```
PlayTestSound(); // здесь playSound, собственно
Window->update(); // здесь прием сообщений
```

Надеюсь, во второй раз мне помогут разобраться с этим. Спасибо.

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы вы потрудились внятно описать проблему. А то у вас все "должен быть, должен быть". А кто, кому и зачем должен - непонятно. У вас в заголовке вопроса стоит упоминание какого-то "бесконечного цикла". В теле же вопроса ни слова по бесконечный цикл нет. Что за бесконечный цикл и к чему он тут упоминался вообще?

Comment: Простите. Пока стриминг происходит, я не могу выйти с приложения, например. Или изменить его размер. Окно не апдейтится с помощью PeekMessage. Точнее, события не принимает.

Comment: код воспроизведения нужно выносить в отдельный поток. И по надобности поднять приоритет потока.

Comment: @KoVadim, хорошо, спасибо, постараюсь сделать.

Comment: @VBS, Вы хотя бы укажите, какой библиотекой пользуетесь для воспроизведения `ogg`. В [первом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/685747/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8B) это было вообще неочевидно. Здесь вроде уже понятно. Возможно библиотека позволяет асинхронно воспроизводить файлы.

Comment: А вот сейчас заметил - [AcousticsLib](http://www.acousticslib.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря @KoVadim и его совету об отдельном потоке, у меня вышел рабочий код, который не задерживается в цикле стримминга и выглядит не так ужасно. Это элементарно с помощью std::thread и его методе join:

```
auto foo_lambda = [] ()
{
    auto sound = ac_lib->LoadSound("gong.ogg");

        sound->SetVolume(0.5f); // Теперь есть возможность изменить громкость источника
        sound->Play();

        while(sound->IsPlaying())
        {
            ac_lib->Streaming(*sound);
        }
};

std::thread thr1(foo); // Create thread.
window()->update(); // Update window.
thr1.join(); // Joining thread.
```

Не смотрите, что загрузка и воспроизведение в одной лямбде, все это для краткости. Как видите необходим современный компилятор с поддержкой std::thread и лябмд. И окно события принимает и стримминг происходит. Большое спасибо @KoVadim за наводку. Изучайте многопоточность.